# C++ overload resolution - ambiguous match

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, ambiguous

I was attempting to experiment with some basic overload resolution concepts using the following test code:

```
void foo()
{
   void F(int x, int y);        // F1
   void F(char x, double y);    // F2
   F('A', 5);
}
```

I've "tried" to comprehend the applicable parts of the C++17 standard and I also looked at cppreference.com.  My understanding is that the conversion sequence for F1 consists of a Promotion and an Exact Match, whereas the conversion sequence for F2 consists of an Exact Match and a Conversion.  cppreference.com states, in part, that

```
...
F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all 
arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of 
F2, and
1) there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than 
the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2
...
```

Based upon all of the above I thought that F1 should be accepted as the best candidate because the worst conversion for F1 is better than the worst conversion for F2.  However, both the Microsoft and minGW compilers generate an "ambiguous" match error.  So obviously I'm missing something.  I would appreciate an explanation of what I am missing and a reference to that information in C++17.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When figuring out which function to call, first all the viable candidates are computed. Each of these functions is then ordered according to the number of implicit conversions that are needed. So given the call:

```
F('a', 5);
```

what are the implicit conversions that need to be done?

```
F1 // 1st argument: char -> int
   // 2nd argument: int -> int (none)

F2 // 1st argument: int -> int (none)
   // 2nd argument: int -> double
```

since both `F1`, and `F2` have to perform exactly one implicit conversion each, they are both considered as equally good, and the call is ambiguous. In particular, both these conversions have the same rank, i.e. they do an integral promotion, and a floating-point promotion, respectively.

There are obviously more rules that cover more cases, but in this case, there is no tie-breaker between the 2 functions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  For F2 the second argument conversion is int->double.  Aside from that, are you saying that for functions having the same number of parameters, where all parameters are of various arithmetic types, the most viable candidate is based entirely upon which has fewer implicit conversions than any of the others, regardless of the ranks of the conversion sequences?

Comment: That's right, edited the answer. The rank does matter I believe, however, in this case, both these conversions have the same rank, so it should still be a tie.

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting Table 13 in the C++17 standard, F1 requires an Integral Promotion whereas F2 requires a Floating-integral conversion.  Thus, the conversion rank for F1 is higher.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, it seems F2 has a different rank then.